# how to find phrases in documents efficiently

Tags: python, language-agnostic

I have a large list of phrases (single and multiple words; some overlapping) and I have a lot of documents. In the end I only want to store a list of phrases (from the large phrase list) per document and not the whole documents. What's an efficient way to achive this? (preferably in python)

example:

```
phrase_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'tree', 'tree house'] // actually a few thousend if not million

// a list of a few thousend documents with longer text
doc_dictionary = {'doc1':"""the cat sat under the tree""",
                  'doc2':"""the dog chased the cat""",
                  'doc3':"""the boy loves his tree house"",}

result_dict = {'doc1': ['cat','tree'], 'doc2': ['dog', 'cat'], 'doc3': ['tree house']}
```

Comment: What kind of search are you performing? Full text, boolean, regex?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of search to use. Anything thats effecient I guess.

Comment: What you are looking for is a fulltext search implementation ;)

Comment: Thanks @Sentinel after searching for "fulltext search python" I found Whoosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need an indexer and search engine, like Lucene for Java.  Perhaps the [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) port will be helpful.

Comment: Hmmm. So what do you suggest? Indexing all documents and then query every item in my phrase-list?

Comment: I've tested Xapian, it has python bindings, easy to use and extremely fast. And yes.

Comment: Thank you peufeu, I was ignorant of Xapian.  I'm glad to know about it.